# C# Geckofx Browser Image Download

Tags: c#, geckofx

I'm trying to download an image from a page.
But it only show (Image Found) if i manually click on right click, i want it to download automatically anyone now a better solution ?
Tried

```
GeckoImageElement img = (GeckoImageElement)wb1.Document.GetElementById("imgcode"); 
if (wb1.CopyImageContents())

MessageBox.Show("done");

if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())

MessageBox.Show("Image Found!!");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geckofx contains a SaveImageElement class which may help you. Eg. the following should copy the 'imgcode' img to the clipboard:

```
wb1.CopyGeckoImageElementToPng(img, 0,0,img.Width,img.Height);
```